# Thread Safe, prevent variables from updating

Tags: c#, variables, threadpool

I have a delegate that is being executed in a threadpool.  A count gets passed in correctly as a variable, however, when the program goes to return the output, The initial value passed in is now the updated version. How can I modify ths so the variable stays the correct value?

```
    private void SetControlText(TextBox TB, string txt)
    {
        if (TB.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                TB.AppendText(txt + "\n");
                TB.Update();
            });
            return;
        }

        TB.Text = txt;
    }

    private void DoWork(OCAdapter.OCAdapter Adapter, OutputForm output, int c, object ThreadContext = null)
    {
        int count = c;
        //output.AppendToOutput("Initializing Adapter: " + count + " Test\n");
        SetControlText(output.OutputBx, "Initializing Adapter: " + count + " Test\n");
        try
        {
            var Test = Adapter.GetBookmarks();
            if (Test != null)
                //output.AppendToOutput("Adapter: " + count + " is valid\n");
                SetControlText(output.OutputBx, "Adapter: " + count + " is valid\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //output.AppendToOutput("Exception occured on adapter: " + count + " Exception: " + ex.Message);
            SetControlText(output.OutputBx, "Exception occured on adapter: " + count + " Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you call DoWork?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, maybe a little bit more code is needed? If you want `DoWork` to not being interrupted by another thread while it is passing `count` to `SetControlText` then you should surround your method body with a `lock` statement : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx I'm not sure this is your issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I actually found out the answer, the threads were using shared memory so they were accessing the variable after it was incremented.

The way I fixed this is by passing in a temporary variable with the count.

Answer (score 0):

Your SetControlText() isn't quite right.  It's doing BOTH an Invoke() and also setting the Text anyways, from the wrong thread, directly below that; every time.

Try something like this instead and see if the problem goes away:

```
    private delegate void SetControlTextDelegate(TextBox TB, string txt);
    private void SetControlText(TextBox TB, string txt)
    {
        if (TB.InvokeRequired)
        {
            TB.Invoke(new SetControlTextDelegate(SetControlText), new object[] { TB, txt });
        }
        else
        {
            TB.AppendText(txt + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to me that his implementation do the same job as yours. He's just using an anonymous delegate instead of a named one. If it's on the main thread then the delegate is invoked on the main thread and `SetControlText` returns. What's the difference with your implementation?

Comment: You're right Simon, I missed the `return;` at the end of the first block.